# How to pass a variable after setInterval completes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code. A fiddle I started which is an isolated version of something I am trying to do.

```
var height;
var count = 0;

var setHeight = setInterval(function() {   
    count++;
    console.log('count');
    if ( count  > 10)
    {
        console.log('done');
        height = 20;
        clearInterval(setHeight);   
    }
},100);

console.log('this is the height -> ' + height);
```

What I would expect (or want to happen) is for the value of `height = 20;` to be outputted in my console.log. The end goal would be to retrieve a variable from my setInterval function after the interval has been cleared.

Right now I get .. *this is the height -> undefined*

**FIDDLE:**

http://jsfiddle.net/GNvG6/8/

**What I am trying to accomplish:**

So the underlying issue is this. I have a function that runs before some elements are loaded in the DOM. So what I am trying to do is keep running the function until an instance of that element exists. Once that happens I then intend to get the height of that element and hand it off to another variable. I am not sure If this will resolve my issue, but I figure if I can get this to work I can at least test it out.

Comment: setInterval delays the execution of the code to run by whatever amount of milliseconds that you have specified. During that delay, the rest of the code will continue executing. Thats why the height is undefined during the console.log. It is defined 100 milliseconds after the code which calls it (the console.log) runs.

Comment: @CoryDanielson, your deleted answer was what I was looking for.

Comment: @KrisHollenbeck by elements you mean images? ( Image load time). Or pure elements?

Comment: You could consider writing a function for this that accepts a callback function for when the condition succeeds. It's asynchronous behaviour basically.

Comment: By elements I mean a set of `<div>`'s with a class on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var height;
var count = 0;

var setHeight = setInterval(function() {   
    count++;
    console.log('count');
    if ( count  > 10)
    {
        console.log('done');
        height = 20;
        reportHeight(height);
        clearInterval(setHeight);   
    }
},100);

function reportHeight(height){
    console.log('this is the height -> ' + height);
}
```

console output is

```
(11) count
done
this is the height -> 20
```

Answer (score 1):

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/8CEjm/1/)

```
var height = 0;                                        // initial value
var count = 0;

var setHeight = setInterval(function() {   
    count++;
    console.log('count and height is still:'+ height); // height is always 0
    if ( count  > 10){
        height = 20;
        console.log('done and height is:'+ height);    // height is finally 20
        clearInterval(setHeight);           
    }
},100);
```

Comment: The outer `height` would not change, as you seem to be shadowing `height` as a function parameter. Actually, the first `console.log` would print `undefined`. http://jsfiddle.net/fiddlegrimbo/8CEjm/

Comment: @PaulGrime you're right I don't know where did that function argument come from ;) removed. Thanks for pointing that.

Answer (score 0):

As you're using jQuery, you could also use `$.Deferred`.

```
// wait for 3 + (0..2) seconds
setTimeout(function () {
    $(document.body).append($("<strong>hello</strong>"));
}, 3000 + 2000 * Math.random());

function waitFor(test, interval) {
    var dfd = $.Deferred();
    var count = 0;
    var id = setInterval(function () {
        console.log(count++);
        var val = test();
        if (undefined !== val) {
            clearInterval(id);
            dfd.resolve(val);
        }
    }, interval);
    return dfd.promise();
}

function waitForEl(selector, interval) {
    return waitFor(function () {
        var els = $(selector);
        return (els.length > 0) ? els : undefined;
    }, interval);
}

waitForEl("strong", 100).then(function (strong) {
    console.log(strong, strong.height());
});
```

[Example in this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddlegrimbo/8CEjm/7/).